# Make a channel app Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm new to `Windows Phone 7.1`. So I have an idea for my app that will follow, update information from a server. Example:

- I have some information: activities that are going on, so I would like to share to people in my club.
- A member of club will have an app contain 1 button (called `"Activity"`): when he clicks the button, he will receive what activities are going on now.

My question is: how to update information of activities to server and how to receive it (using `HTTPRequest` or anything else? )

Sorry, my English is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [`HttpClient`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx) to perform Get and Post http requesst.

It's quite easy to use if you understand the basic ideas of http.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
string responseBodyAsText = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(“your-url.com”);
```